# How to tab in contenteditable without losing focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Everytime I press tab, it loses focus on the table instead of inserting a white space. How do I fix it so that tabbing just inserts a regular tab space?

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery` you can do something like this:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.which === 9){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html($(this).html() + '&#009'); //insert tab character
  }
})
```

Make sure to have your css as

```
[contenteditable] {
  white-space : pre-wrap;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is just the basics. Because if your cursor is not at the end of the text, things mess up. You should obtain the cursor position, and insert the tab at that position.

To deal with these issues, you need to expend your event handler a bit more:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 9) {
    //prevent from tabbing out 
    e.preventDefault();

    var ce = this;
    var $ce = $(ce);
    var html = $ce.html();
    var textNode = ce.firstChild;
    var range = document.createRange();
    var position = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;

    //place tab at cursor position
    $ce.html([html.slice(0, position), '&#009', html.slice(position)].join(''));

    //reset cursor position and place it after the tab
    ce.focus();
    range.setStart(textNode, position + 1);
    range.setEnd(textNode, position + 1);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
});
```

This will place a tab at the right position, and resets the cursor.

You can see a working fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/q7cs5q4s/). Be aware though, that this is very rudimentary and it is very likely it will only work in chrome. For other browser support you should find it out yourself. Also the edge cases of starting and ending with a tab character will fail in here, but this will give you a little nudge in the right direction

Comment: Doesn't work. Is it something wrong with my code?   
<div id="editor1" contenteditable="true" style="margin-left:30em">
  </div>
  <script>
  $('contenteditable').on('keyup', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.which === 9){
    $(this).html($(this).html() + '&#009'); //insert tab character
  }
})
  </script>

All this is inside my body tag.

Comment: That does not look like my code.. `keydown`, `preventDefault()` should be inside the `if`

Answer (score 0):

use below code. I have not tested it but it should work fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      if(event.which == 9)
      {
         jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val()+""+&#009);
      }

    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't type anymore ;)

Comment: yes. I have made changes. event.preventDefault dont work here

Comment: **This answer makes no sense**... When you tab, that does not means you want to always append a tab. That means: 1. don't lose **focus** from contenteditable; 2. insert a tab at the exact **caret position**. 3. Handle tab specially if we have text selection. 4. What about Shift+Tab? You handle **none**. And what is `""+&#009` anyways?

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan !! You can add your code for more detailed information so I can check and learn more from you :)